# How to create Mongodb Shell command which will be run by nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

As we know that there are several Modules available for doing the MongoDB Task with Nodejs. But I want to Create a shell command by which I automate the Process So that Every day around 5:00 pm run the Automated command to do backups with the help of CronJob.
I follow Some tutorial And found that first create the js file and then pass the code which is as follow:

```
print(db.CollectionName.count());
```

And on cmd Run the command i.e

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/YourDBName "E:\localtion of the File"
```

By this command will execute.
But I want to Create the automated process which is done by Nodejs CronJob. Want to Do Backup from One server and Restore it to another Server. Replication is Already Implemented. So guys don't Divert mind in terms of replication.
Any help is Appreciated

Comment: I don't understand why you need to execute shell script to automate the process. You can use node cron module to run any nodejs code at some specific time. Provided that your application is running. Write some nodejs code that does the backup and restore job and run it whith node cron when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node.js **[child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)** to create the backup.

```
const {
    spawn
} = require('child_process');

const options = {};

const child = spawn('mongodump', ['--db', 'DB-NAME'], options);
```

**Restore :**

```
const child2 = spawn('mongorestore', ['--db', 'NEWDB-NAME', '<path of backup dir>/DB-NAME'], options);
```

Comment: and for restore??

Comment: const child2 = spawn('mongorestore', ['--db', 'NEWDB-NAME', 'path of dumpfolder/dump/<DB-NAME>'], options);

Comment: dear I want to do this stuff without any modules. If you have any idea about that then let me know.

Comment: It's inbuilt module in node.js. You don't have to use the external module.